# Why is it slower to get a Select when in where clause you use variables?

Tags: sql, variables, select, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

I have the following query that takes approximately 2 minutes to return an output.

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME 
SET @today = GETDATE() 

SELECT con.* 
FROM GAS_consumptions con 
WHERE con.createdDate >= @today
```

I noticed that if I use this, it takes less than a second

```
SELECT con.* 
FROM GAS_consumptions con 
WHERE con.createdDate >= '2015-06-22'
```

Why does that happen? I need the first query since the date can vary from day to day.

Comment: What RDBMS? SQL Server? MySQL? Something else?

Comment: Does `EXPLAIN` show any difference between them? Did you run the second query after the first (in which case large parts of the data may already be cached in RAM?)

Comment: Forgot the name of it, but there usually is a system to look at the relational algebra generated by an RDBMS. Might give you some clues if you look at that. Yes, EXPLAIN is what it's called!

Comment: If you specify one, specific value, SQL Server can optimize it's query for that one, single value; it can look at the data distribution and find the optimal execution plan. If you provide a **parameter**, the query optimizer has to "optimize" for any possible value - therefore, the execution plan will most likely be less efficient than for one, single value

Comment: Do you have an index over createdDate? Can you try to add one if not?

Comment: Billy ONeal - No, I ran the queries separately
Renzo - Yes, it does have an index already

Comment: @Victor: If you ran the queries separately, you mean you rebooted the server between running them? Just because you executed them in two different sessions doesn't mean that SQL server hasn't cached huge portions of your data in RAM making whichever query you run second much faster.

Comment: What is the datatype of `CreatedDate`?

Comment: CreatedDate is a DATETIME

Comment: How many rows does `GAS_consumptions` have?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a literal value in a query SQL Server will generate a query plan that is optimised for that specific value.

For example if you have a non clustered index on createdDate, the query optimiser can get a good estimate on the number of rows with `createdDate >= '2015-06-22'`. If this a small proportion of the rows on the table the optimal query will find the matching records in the createdDate index, then lookup the rest of the selected columns for the matching rows from the table.

When you use a variable in the WHERE clause SQL Server generates a single query plan that will be used for all possible values of @today. The plan generated is intended to be optimal for an arbitrary value of @today, but a single plan can only be optimal for a certain number of rows being selected.

Say the estimate for the average number of rows selected is half the number of rows in the table, in this case it is estimated to be more efficient to scan the entire table to filter the records rather than filtering the createdDate index and then having to do a large number of lookups on the table to get the rest of the selected columns.

The issue is that SQL Server is using a single query plan for queries that can have radically different row counts. The reason a single query plan is used for all values of @today is often it is more expensive to compile a optimal query than to just run a sub-optimal one. In your example this obviously isn't the case.

There are ways to change this behaviour:

1) You can also get Sql Server to generate a single plan but optimize it for a pre-determined value of @today

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME 
SET @today = GETDATE() 

SELECT con.* 
FROM GAS_consumptions con 
WHERE con.createdDate >= @today
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@today = '2015-06-22'))
```

This should produce the same query as using the `con.createdDate >= '2015-06-22'` predicate and could provide a nice solution if your application is always going to be querying for records after a pre determined date.

2) Specifying the recompile option will cause a new query plan to be generated every time it is run, this allows a query optimised for the specific @today value.

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME 
SET @today = GETDATE() 

SELECT con.* 
FROM GAS_consumptions con 
WHERE con.createdDate >= @today
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

This should produce the same query as using the `con.createdDate >= '2015-06-22'` predicate.

WARNING: RECOMPLING QUERIES CAN ALSO BE SLOW. USING THE RECOMPILE OPTION CAN DEGRADE PERFOMANCE. USE AS LAST RESORT. ETC.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround. Apply this commnad:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS GAS_consumptions WITH FULLSCAN, NORECOMPUTE
```

Do some querys for some minutes.
Mesure again.

Take in mind that `, NORECOMPUTE` will requiere the execution of this command on a regular basis, because it stops the way that sqlserver generates statistics in the future.

In a similar case I got, this was "the solution". I don't know why it happens